# Research Paper : Virtual Node Algorithm for Changing mesh Topology

Tags: graphics, simulation, mesh, medical

I was referring the paper `Virtual Node Algorithm for Changing Mesh Topology During Simulation` .

I have one very basic question regarding it. A **`node one ring`** is been used in this paper. I am confused as to what it refers to .

Context in which it is used is in :

```
For each distinct scoop cut out of a node’s one ring, a virtual copy of the 
central  node is created and donated to the nodes within the given scoop
to give the mesh the degrees of freedom needed to break apart.
```

Please help to understand the same .

Comment: I was wondering , if we have a forum in which we can discuss about the research papers and clear our doubts regarding them.

Comment: I haven't read the paper, but a node's one-ring is usually the set of vertices that are adjacent to this node (connected by a single edge). Similarly, the two-ring is the set of vertices that can be reached by crossing two edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A node's one ring means the set of triangles that are incident on the node. If just read that paper recently, if you have any question, you can post on the comments